# Can I view a user's browser history if the history/cache has been cleared?

Tags: windows, web-browser, forensics

A client wants to track a specific employee's browsing habits. Assuming that the employee knows how to clear their browser history, is there any way to recover the history so it can be read by BrowserHistoryView or some other software?

Comment: I comes to my mind that an employee may use Tor service, or similar. Which will make his traffic encrypted and much harder to spy on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two ways, the hard and the easy.

The hard way: use forensic software to recover deleted files, identify the folders and files responsible for history and cache, and read those files.

The easy way: use forced proxy company-wide, and configure the network to only allow browsing by using this proxy. With user authentication enabled, it's possible to know exactly what every employee is accessing.

Either way, usually the employer have to tell every employee about the inspection and require them to acknowledge that they know about the monitoring. It depends on your jurisdiction and current laws, but usually is a good thing to do.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation on what forensic software to use for this purpose?

Comment: Forensic software will depend on your OS, but on most cases, any "undelete" kind of software can be used for undeleting the files.

Comment: Note also that depending upon the browser and its *private browsing* variant, forensic recovery may not be possible. Firefox in *private browsing mode* never writes the history to disk, so there's nothing to recover.

Comment: An alternative to a forced proxy would be recording *Netflow* data at the corporate gateway router.

Comment: Yet another approach is to place monitoring software directly on the end user machine(s). This assume that the machines are corporate owned with standard disclaimers.

Comment: Netflow cannot help if the user is using DNS over HTTPS and the server uses Encrypted SNI. So a corporate proxy with a custom CA can decrypt the DNS-over-HTTPS request, and the HTTPS connection afterwards.

Comment: Netflow will still show the connection IPs and data volumes. If the objective is to decrypt, that's a different issue.

Comment: Connection IP may not mean anything if it's behind Clouflare or something like that. It could be anything, could be a bank, porn, competitor, job board, image board...

Comment: While your statement concerning Encrypted SNI is accurate, Encrypted SNI is still a draft experimental proposal. It's not yet common nor commonly supported.